# Add new rows to existing table from external data with no duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with existing workers' names, IDs, and addresses.

These workers are hired and fired many times.

I pull a report (external data from a website) that lists these workers' names, IDs, and addresses that are currently employed.

Instead of adding and deleting the rows of these workers on my table(the table on the MASTER sheet) to match the report(the data on the EXTERNAL DATA sheet), I would like to add the rows of workers from the report(EXTERNAL DATA sheet) to my table(MASTER sheet) automatically without duplicates.

The reason I need to add the whole row is because I have more columns in the table(on the MASTER sheet) so I can add their job title, shift, and incentive pay. So I need to delete the whole row when I delete the worker...

I need some code to add rows from the external data table(EXTERNAL DATA sheet) on one sheet to my MASTER table on another sheet without duplicate workers.

This code works great on my sheet now. I might be able to adapt this code with some help...

```
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Code to move row from FIRED sheet to MASTER sheet when “REHIRED” is 
'selected in column J
  If Target.Column = 2 Then
' The line below is where I should change to something to compare if there 
'is a new number 
'in the "NUMBER" column of the "EXTERNAL DATA" sheet then move the row to  
'the "MASTER" table. 
  If Target = "REHIRED" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    nxtRow = Sheets("MASTER").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Target.EntireRow.Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("MASTER").Range("A" & nxtRow)
    Target.EntireRow.Delete
  End If
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub`
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Is your question about the code you posted, or about something else?  Without knowing what your existing data looks like, and what the report looks like, it's difficult to suggest anything.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. How can I post the spreadsheet?

Comment: You can use (eg) a linked google sheet to show the layout of the two sheets, or show a simple example directly in your question.

Comment: How about this?                                       https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a9M2zar88ZKiVNnOEFEUC0IIK-eaCY0AuDurgJIBfVA/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: So I need to take the data row from the EXTERNAL DATA sheet and insert the new row to the MASTER sheet without duplicates (I changed the their ID numbers in the first column for protection). And I want to make sure that the row is added to the table on the MASTER sheet not just added to the next row down below the table.

Comment: What have you tried/  You should be able to loop over the external data, and use `Match()` or `Find()` to check for matches in the master table.  BTW unless you spent a *lot* of time cleaning up that workbook before posting it, I would take it down.

Comment: The only sensitive data is their number and I altered them so I should be okay... I'm really new to VBA code, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: updated/tested.  Assumes both sets of data are formatted as Tables/ListObjects:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim lo As ListObject, loExt As ListObject, lr As ListRow
    Dim rw As Range, shtExt As Worksheet, f As Range, shtMaster As Worksheet
    Dim rwNew As Range

    Set shtExt = Sheets("external data")
    Set shtMaster = Sheets("master")
    Set lo = shtMaster.ListObjects(1) 'or use the table name
    Set loExt = shtExt.ListObjects(1) 'assumes the external data is a listobject

    For Each lr In loExt.ListRows

        'try to find the Id on the master sheet
        Set f = lo.ListColumns(1).Range.Find(lr.Range(1).Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If f Is Nothing Then

            'no match: add a new row to the table
            Set rwNew = shtMaster.ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add().Range
            'populate the new row
            rwNew.Cells(1).Value = lr.Range(1).Value
            rwNew.Cells(2).Value = lr.Range(2).Value
            rwNew.Cells(3).Value = lr.Range(3).Value
            'etc transfer any other required values...

        End If
    Next lr

End Sub
```

Comment: I got some errors on this and I can see how this would be a little hard... Check out my spreadsheet again. I can use a power query and convert the external data to a table and match the table names on the "MASTER" and "EXTERNAL DATA" worksheets which should make it easier(I updated the worksheet with this example). Would this make it easier?

Comment: I'm not a Power Query user so I can't help with that part.  "Some erors" doesn't tell me much about what problems you might be having though

Comment: I use this code to move rows to the "MASTER" sheet when "REHIRED" is selected in column 8 on the "FIRED" sheet. Maybe I can adapt this code

Comment: See my edits above.  This works for me using your posted sheet (after converting "external data" to a listobject)

Comment: I have some code that I may be able to adapt but it won't let me post the code. Says it's too long. How do I post the code on here?

Comment: I only need to compare the ""NUMBER" column on both sheets and then if the there is a new number on the "EXTERNAL DATA" sheet I need to move that row to the "MASTER" sheet.... I wish I could post my code on here.

Comment: I got "run-time error 9"   "Subscript out of range"

Comment: On which line?  And using the updated code, or my original answer?

Comment: The line starting with "For Each" from your updated code.....I would like for you to see this clean and simple code but how do I post it?

Comment: You can update your question with the code you're using. Use the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Check out the code on my question now. I think it might be promising. Like I said before, I only need to look at the "NUMBER" columns in each table and then look for a new entry and then move the row from "EXTERNAL DATA" sheet to "MASTER" sheet.

Comment: I posted code which in my testing (using the workbook you posted) works fine.  The other code you posted is useless for what you want to do.  If that's how you really want to approach it I'm out.

Comment: I may have workers with the same last name so I will definitely need to just focus on the "NUMBER" columns of each sheet as it uses unique numbers.

Comment: Yeah, if you say it's useless then I'll drop it.

Comment: re - last name vs number - I know that, and that's what the code does.  Did you try it?

Comment: It gives me "Subscript out of range" on "Set loExt" line

Comment: Should it be "For Each lr In loExt.ListRows(1)"?... Nope, that didn't work. Neither did using ListObects instead of ListRows... Hmmm

Comment: Is the data on your "external" list formatted as a Table/Listobject ?

Comment: Select the data table  - is the `INSERT >> Table` ribbon icon greyed out?  If it isn't, then click it to convert the data to a Table.  Your posted file has slicers on the master sheet, so I assumed you were familiar with tables/listobjects...